# How to send facebook invites for non gaming android apps

Tags: android, facebook

Currently I am working on a restaurant app and have integrated Facebook login for it. However the problem arose when I tried to incorporate the app invite feature. I went through my official Facebook docs and concluded (if I am not wrong) that facebook invites is available only for gaming (canvas) apps. However android apps like flipkart have incorporated such feature so I don't think it is impossible.

What I want is that if a user has used "login with facebook" feature then on "invite friends" button click, he sees a dialog with a list of his facebook friends. From this list, he can choose the friends he want to and send invite to them for dining out.

Kindly help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is all explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Comment: @WizKid I went through the link and read all about app invites for native android app. Although they have given the complete mechanism to open a dialog to send invite but there is not a mechanism on how I can show a complete user friend list for sending dialog.

Comment: That is because it isn't possible

Comment: @WizKid Are you sure about this? and can you provide me some basis behind your comment because I am creating an app for a client and he wants this feature so I need to show him some relevant documents if I say that something is not technically possible.

Comment: The FAQ is not enough?

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for the link and your reply. I think it should be enough. Thanks again for all your help.